# When is the determinant map a ring homomorphism?

Tags: matrices, ring-theory

I showed that the determinant map det:Mat$_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a homomorphism when $n=1$, but not when $n=0$ or $n=2$.

I know that for $n>2$ it is not possible to be a homomorphism either, but how can I explain this?

Comment: Does the determinant take a sum to a sum? This should answer your question.

Comment: @AlexM. What do you mean by taking a sum to a sum?

Comment: I mean taking $A+B$ into $\det A + \det B$. Do you know what a ring homomorphism is?

Answer (score 4):

In order to show that this is not a ring homomorphism, it's enough to find even one pair of matrices $A,B$ such that $\det(A+B)\neq \det(A)+\det(B)$.

I suggest taking $A=B=I_n$...

Comment: That part I understand, but how can I say that it holds for $n>2$?

Comment: Nothing I said requires that $n=2$. Do you know what the determinant of the $n\times n$ identity matrix is? What about the $n\times n$ diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are all $2$s?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was kind of fixated on the $n=2$ stuff :/